# Audio drops intermittently over HDMI

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, hdmi

When connected to my TV via HDMI, the audio drops out for about a second or two at a time, every 10-20 seconds.  This problem existed on fedora and pop OS as well. this problem does not occur on windows.  This problem does not occur while using the headphone jack.  I have tried disabling auto mute in alsa mixer which did not fix the problem.  I have an intel 12400F CPU and RTX 2060 GPU.

Comment: You've provided no product/release details of the OS you're asking about.  Ubuntu LTS releases have different kernel stack choices; which cause different kernel modules (aka *drivers*) to be used that may provide an easy fix, but you're without any actual specifics except for mention of off-topic OSes.  Have you tried a different cable? or ruled out hardware explanations?

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 22.04 LTS.  It is not a hardware issue as I have tried multiple cables and the same hardware functions as expected with no audio drops on windows.